# UITextView multi-line spelling problem - Swift

Tags: swift

I am using UITextView, I enter the UITextView by pressing the enter key and moving to the bottom line or pressing the switch from the keyboard to the bottom line. I check what I wrote with print but it does not see the word I wrote on the bottom line, but only the word I write on the first line. How to add and print multiple lines of text correctly.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textInputArea: UITextView!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you inspecting `UITextView` content? Try checking it that way

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var input: UITextView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        input.delegate = self
    }
    
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        print(textView.text)
    }
}
```

In that case you should receive something like that

> Optional("aaaa\n\n\nBbbbb\n\n\nCcccc")

where every "\n" is a new line.